# Why Vue ElementUI Select component sends text instead of value?

Tags: vue.js

When I submit form by clicking submit button with some option selected in Select component of ElementUI, I recieve text of this option. Is it possible to send value? I can see value from Vue app but not at server side.

```
<div id="app">
    <el-form :inline="true" :model="formInline">
        <el-form-item>
        <el-select
                label="clients"
                name = "client_id"
                v-model="formInline.client_id"
                filterable
                remote
                placeholder="Client"
                :remote-method="getClient"
                :loading="loading">
            <el-option
                    v-for="item in clients"
                    :key="item.id"
                    :label="item.name"
                    :value="item.id">
            </el-option>
        </el-select>
        </el-form-item>
        <el-form-item>
            <el-date-picker
                    name = "date"
                    v-model="formInline.date"
                    type="month"
                    placeholder="Month">
            </el-date-picker>
        </el-form-item>
        <el-form-item>
            <el-button type="primary" @click="onSubmit" native-type="submit">Ok</el-button>
        </el-form-item>
    </el-form>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6gqc5dj1/1/

Comment: What value especially? Date?

Comment: @WaldemarIce, no, client_id